# google-services.json location in the project tree

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am following this manual and I am unsure where I should exactly copy the file `google-services.json`? There's many folders containing an app folder and I am trying to develop this for `android wear`. Any guide would be really great. So far I have put it here:
[image]

Link to [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messagin%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Try%20Cloud%20Messaging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured I copied it into the right folder. Here's the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client?configured=true) I found which helped me:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You need to put the google-services.json file in the app module inside your project. That file will be read by the com.google.gms.google-services Gradle plugin.

Comment: @MnemonicFlow what happens if we have prod/dev environments set up, and need to use different configuration files based on the `productFlavor`?

Comment: @ZakTaccardi Unfortunately the plugin does not support such use cases yet. If you look at its source code from https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/view#files by downloading the google-services-x.y.z-___-sources.jar , you'll see it only looks in the module's root folder for a file named google-services.json aka the directory from where you invoke the plugin with `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: @MnemonicFlow all the plugin does is generate android resources, right? I am guessing those values can be overridden? My answer here is untested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31255824/891242

Comment: @jalal Hello mam,any idea about aviary sdk ?

Answer (score 32):

Was configuring Firebase for android app and it gives good description on these. As the accepted answer says i**t should goes in app folder**. Adding images for better understanding of place to put it in and configuration needed.

[image]

[image]