# Google AppInvite: Email is not sent, while SMS is sent

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

I am using google libraries with

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'
```

And my appinvite library version is

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.8.0'
```

While using appinvites, I can easily send invites using SMS and email. But on the receiving end only SMS is received, I can't send email.

Is it a bug in library or I am missing something else?

**Edit:** Everything else in my code follows google's [appinvite guidelines](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app).

Comment: Facing same issue. Code is working perfectly, I even get the appinvite ids from the framework, the SMS is received, but emails are not received. Wtf...? Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the App invent demo app [here](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/start?configured), and followed the steps.

I can send the email and it can be received.

You can try and compare source code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/appinvites/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/appinvite) with yours.

Maybe you forget connected the `GoogleApiClient` at begin. Note that in the top `build.gradle`, it contains:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

Comment: Do I have to stick with beta1 version? The current version is 1.3.0, which is 4th iteration, Plus we have another google apis enabled like plus, maps, location and gcm. So I am not willing to revert to beta1.

Comment: No, you don't need to stick with beta1. I also tried the `1.3.0`. It shows that it works as well. You can try and compare source code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/appinvites/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/appinvite) with yours.

Comment: @ZoomAzure I'm also facing the same problem, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like missing google-services.json. You need to put the google-services.json file in the app module inside your project.

See [google-services.json location in the project tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193158/google-services-json-location-in-the-project-tree)