# FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful in Android Instant apps

Tags: android, firebase, android-instant-apps, google-play-services

I am currently working on an exiting Android application in order to create an Instant apps version.

My Android Studio is now split into several modules :

- the business object module (which is a library)
- the base -feature- module
- the moduleA -feature- module
- the app module (which is a phone/tablet module)
- the instant module (which is an instant apps module)

My instant app module can be compiled and launched on a phone/tablet but each time it crashes due to Firebase issues. I have the following message into the logcat :

> I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/guides/analytics.html) the Firebase library is compatible with Instant Apps, but I am pretty sure that I do not move the google-services.json file into the right place in my project...

Here what I have done :

1. I defined the following classpath dependencies into the build.gradle file of the Android Studio project : classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
2. I put the google-services.json file into my module base (because the documentation asks for it)

Now, if I try to apply the plugin (apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services') into the build.gradle file of the base module, I cannot compile. I have the following message :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':base:processGooglePlayProductionDebugFeatureGoogleServices'.
>
> > No matching client found for package name 'com.mycompany.myapp.base'

In fact, the package name defined into the google-services.json file is the one use by the app (because according to the [documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#4) the base library cannot have the same package name as the installed android app.

I also tried to apply the plugin into the build.gradle files of the installed app and into the instant apps module leaving the google-services.json file into the base module. The app compile but I have the log : "FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful".

So I tried moving the google-services.json file into my instant app module but I still have the log : "FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful"

I also tried to force the initialization calling the static method initializeApp from the FirebaseApp class but the log persists.

I cannot find an example of implementation on the web. In fact, the [Google Sample repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps) does not use a google-services.json file.

Thank you in advance for your help !

**Edit :** Here the dependencies of my modules :

The dependencies of my base -feature- module :

```
  implementation project(':businessobject')
  feature project(':moduleA')
  application project(':app')
```

The dependencies of my moduleA -feature- module :

```
api project(':base')
api project(':businessobject')
```

The dependencies of my app module (which is a phone/tablet module) :

```
implementation (project(':base'))
implementation (project(':businessobject'))
implementation (project(':moduleA'))
```

The dependencies of my instant module (which is an instant apps module) :

```
implementation project(':base')
implementation project(':businessobject')
implementation project(':moduleA')
```

Comment: Per doc (https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/guides/analytics.html#adding_google_analytics_to_an_instant_app_project), google-services.json file should be placed into base feature/ module: switch to Project view and move google-services.json file into your base module root directory. This SO post illustrates how to configure Firebase for android app https://stackoverflow.com/a/40800682/8320998

Comment: This sample app shows how to integrate Google Analytics for Firebase into an instant app: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/analytics
After you clone this sample app, you need to add project to Firebase Console, then download generated for this project google-services.json file and place it in your base/ module.

Comment: How did you solve it? Im in the same situation

Answer (score 2):

> because according to the documentation the base library cannot have
>   the same package name as the installed android app.

I think the documentation is a bit out of date.  Each "**feature**" module needs to use a different package name, because that's what's used to generate the name of the **R class**.  AFAIK there's no reason why you can't have the "**base**" feature use the same package name as the app itself.

It seems like the "**`google-services`**" plugin needs to be updated for the "**feature**" plugin to use the *application ID* rather than the name specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` (*which will be overwritten later to be the same as the application ID*).

tl;dr---changing the package name of "**base**" to "*com.mycompany.myapp*" should get things working.

Comment: Im having the same problem but I dont understand your solution, can you explain it better please?

Comment: @PabloCegarra were you able to find a solution to this ?

Comment: Yes... I started a new app with a single feature following the basic Android example, now is it working

Comment: so changing the package name of base to that app is the only solution

Comment: Instant apps are a headhache, now I can run my instant app from the play store but firebase says initialization unsuccessful

Comment: @PabloCegarra any luck solving the issue ?

Comment: @Ezio no sorry, I deleted my instant app, to much pain xD

Comment: I am afraid, I dont have that luxury. need to fix this thing