# Firebase Analytics not working with Instant App or Normal App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, android-instant-apps

I have an app that is modularized to support instant-apps.

App modules:

- app
- instantapp
- base
- main
- detail
- search

I tried to add Firebase by adding:

- classpath '`com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1`' → to the **Project Level build.gradle**
- api "`com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${versions.firebase}`" → to the Base Module
- apply plugin: '`com.google.gms.google-services`' → to the bottom of the **Base Module**
- *google-services.json* → to the base module folder

When I run the **non-instant app** I receive the following errors:

> I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
>
> E/FA: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.
>
> I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11720
>
> I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>
> I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>           adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.punpuf.chacaraselazer.app
>
> E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See https://goo(...)
>
> E/FA: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
>
> I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used

And when I run the **instant app** I receive the following error:

> V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 1799580119
>
> E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure. (...) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.job.IJobScheduler.cancel(int)' on a null object reference
>
> I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful

If I add the following line: "`FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)`", not only does it receive the previous errors, it also crashes:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.punpuf.chacaraselazer.app, PID: 11273 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{(...)}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.job.IJobScheduler.cancel(int)' on a null object reference

So my question is how can I get Firebase Analytics to work, and not crash on both my instant and non-instant version of my app.

Although this question is a bit similar to [FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful in Android Instant apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666474/) , mine not contain the same type of errors.

Update:
I've created a new Firebase Project, and updated my google-services.json, but still didn't work.

Here are my gradle files:

- project: https://gist.github.com/Punpuf/8582fa3610a1c3dea13627e1207a6064
- app: https://gist.github.com/Punpuf/2104ffe0c90927cb79944860a7cb6c46
- instantapp: https://gist.github.com/Punpuf/233d96e91293a2a14e8fdf50092edd2d
- base: https://gist.github.com/Punpuf/e1646f67d8a6094773c390d2df209eae
- main: https://gist.github.com/Punpuf/f8bdd8789b11d274afdb1c51f490ed25
- detail: https://gist.github.com/Punpuf/0a4f87b4fb512557ffe6cd110ce667de
- search: https://gist.github.com/Punpuf/455e28b38baad23294dda6c9592586a2

I've also tried replacing firebase analytics dependency with firebase messaging and I still received the "**FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful**" **error**.

Comment: A sample for Firebase Analytics in combination with Android Instant Apps is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/analytics)

Comment: I've already seen it, I've also compared my gradle files with theirs to check if I had made any mistakes.

Comment: just use firebase assistant, go to Tools>Firebase>connect to firebase and it will add the dependencies of firebase in the gradle

Comment: I had already tried that

Comment: @Marcola can you share sample project to understand clearly your concern if still have issues.

Comment: I can't tell what Firebase version you are using, is it updated to 11.6.2? https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Comment: Also, this could also be an issue of an outdated `Google Play Services for Instant Apps` Uninstall it and then run an instant app to make sure the latest version gets installed.

Comment: If it still doesn't work and fede1608's solution also doesn't work, then I would suggest you to submit your project to Google's https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 They will take a look at it. (also, please be sure to provide here the link to that filed bug)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had the same problem, I solved it adding the google-services.json to both base and app module and applying the google services plugin in both build.gradle files

Comment: Thank you!! For other people experiencing this issue, you may also have to edit your app module google-services.json file's  "package_name"  inside 
 "client_info"  to the package name of your app module

Comment: @fede1608 I followed the same steps but I am getting StackOverflowError at GoogleServicesPlugin.getAllDependencies ERROR Log: https://justpaste.it/1hhfv Any suggestion

Comment: @Ajit Sorry no idea, It seems that there is a loop somewhere, maybe you are linking both build gradle to each other?

Comment: @fede1608 This issue occur when apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to base module

Comment: @Ajit Can you share both build.gradle?

Comment: This solution works however I find it odd to have to copy configuration for Firebase with Instant Apps. I'd rather prefer a solution where there's only one google-services.json.