# Using Firebase on Instant App on Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, android-instant-apps

I'm working in migrating App to support ***Instant App***.

So, I have modularized my project structure as follow

[image: My Project Structure]

But when I'm adding ***Firebase***, only **firebase Analytics** can works with it.
Another feature like ***Firebase Auth***, ***Storage, Firestore***, And ***Database*** are **not working in here**.

**I Got an Error :**

```
Firebase App Not Initialized.
Although I have declared FirebaseApp.Initialize(this) through Activity 
or Application class.
```

*But Firebase Analytic can works just fine.*

[image: Here my Code in an Activity]

[image: Here my Gradle]

Please help if anyone know how to solve this.

Comment: I've had this too and was unable to find a solution.

Comment: can you check this url for understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292901/firebase-support-library-dependency-conflict-for-instant-apps, might it help you.

Comment: Can you check this URL for more help https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Comment: @PragatiSingh does that take into an account this is an instant app?

Comment: @PragatiSingh yeah, thanks, but I had been able to use firebase on legacy apps. But Firebase still not works in Instant App Project.

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: or can you check https://firebase.google.com/support/ for more help.

Comment: Have you tried initializing it in your `Application` class? I have Firebase working in my AIA and that's the only difference I see.

Comment: @KyleVenn Can you show us in step by step? Firebase Analytics can work seamlessly but not for the others. Yeah I have tried initialized it on my Application class which declared as Application name in manifest.

Comment: My apologies, I only have Firebase Analytics working as well. That's the only one we've needed. One thought that comes to mind is that the other Firebase libraries most likely require permissions that aren't allowed in AIA. Anything using disk isn't allowed in AIA.

Comment: @DarariNurAmali, I hope your problem has been resolve or you have file a bug to google,please confirm. Thanks!

Comment: @PragatiSingh nope, I still have a problem here. Can you teach me how to send a bug to google? what should I send?

Comment: @DarariNurAmali, You can follow this link, information available 
 there to help `how to file bug`. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: @DarariNurAmali , have you report it to google team? if yes, you can update link to here.

Comment: We are having the same error on our instant app. Any update on this? Any link to a google bug?

Comment: I found this related report:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72422073

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576360/firebase-analytics-not-working-with-instant-app-or-normal-app

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on this [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72422073) there is a problem on the documentation and/or on the google service plugin.
To resolve it you have to add the `google-service.json` and the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services` code in every module and build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem and solved by doing this:

1. Add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
2. Add `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`
3. Add `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` bellow `apply plugin: 'com.android.application[features]'`

In every build.gradle module file