# Default Activity not found adding firebase

Tags: firebase, android-instant-apps

I have an instant app, and its working nice, but if I add this line to my `base/build.gradle` then I cant run my app/installed, note that I can run it with a url.

```
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

The error is "Default activity not found".
Removing the compile firebase, *voilá* the activity is found.

Using `implementation` instead of `api` the app runs nice, but firebase says "installation unsucessful" but using `api` and running it as a instant app firebase says "successful"

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCodeInstalled
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionNameInstalled
    }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

Manifest app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.app" />
```

Manifest base:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="aia-compat-api-min-version"
            android:value="1" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Seems like the problem is adding firebase to my /app/build.gradle I dont know why

Comment: This seems to be a known issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666474/firebaseapp-initialization-unsuccessful-in-android-instant-apps

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can find which manifest is affected and needs a modification. It should be the module where the plugin is applied, but check the merged manifest and look for an error that says: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> ...

Comment: modify it according to that suggestion and your issue should be resolved

Comment: This can happen when gradle fails to sync. Are you able to build your project from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

In the `base/manifest`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="aia-compat-api-min-version"
        android:value="1" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="com.menuymenu.android.app.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge"/>

</application>
```