# Default Activity not found: Android Studio

Tags: android

so i started working on this location based app and everything was working just fine but as soon as added FIREBASE authentication to my app, the error comes up and says default activity not found. After that when i go to EDIT CONFIG and set the default activity to main activity, a new error pops up and says Main Activity not found in Manifest.XML. I also tried to start a new app and did the same thing, same error comes up again.
Below is my Manifest.XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.locus">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="22"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.locus.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936635/default-activity-not-found-adding-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the Edit configuration launch option has selected as the default activity.
and use

`File-> invalidate caches and restart`

Answer (score 0):

```
File-> invalidate caches and restart
```

Archu your answer worked for me.