# Generating signed APK

Tags: android, apk, release

I'm trying to build my first signed APK for release and I got some error. It seems that work perfectcly but now I just cant generate APK. I've done research but couldn't find anything.

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

**Gradle version: 4.8**,
**Android Plugin Version 3.1.4**
and here's my app gradle screenshot: [link](https://prnt.sc/ksctp6)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

This is from assembleDebug:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)


27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
```

I used to have other problems with layout and deprecated functions but I fixed it. One of them just disappear but I had done nothing :-)

```
unchecked call to execute
new getToken().execute();
where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
```

Things that I have already tried:

```
1. android.enableAapt2=false
2. checked if strings (for character i.e. chinese)
3. added classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }


and many more but NOTHING! Same error -.-
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Warnings: Could not find google-services.json while looking in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565761/gradle-warnings-could-not-find-google-services-json-while-looking-in)

Answer (score 1):

Check your PNG images, corrupted maybe or not real png (jpeg for example)

You can get the list of unreal PNGs by typing following command in android terminal

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" | xargs -L 1 -I{} file  -I {} | grep -v 'image/png; charset=binary$'
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Could not find** `google-services.json` while looking in

Probably your project needs `google-services.json`. Place the file in `/app` folder of project.

Since you are using FireBase, you may be forgotten to place the file in there and placing the file from FireBase console in there will help.

**Check this out:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/40800682/4409113

Comment: there's json file in /app

Comment: Using latest version of `google-services` will help i suppose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47565868/4409113

Comment: That should be pasted with full logcat errors + codes in another question I'm afraid. Please use Ask question for the further questions. Thanks